# Why can't this universal CSS style be overwritten?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I'm trying to equally distribute 5 li items of varying width as outlined via [this](http://www.goldenapplewebdesign.com/css-equally-spaced-horizontal-elements/) method. It works fine in Chrome but FireFox and Safari shows the li elements broken onto several lines.

The li elements are those at the top of this page with the white text against the red background:
http://www.mountainwarehouse.com/?_vis_test_id=46&_vis_opt_random=0.35009177937172353&_vis_hash=c587be8bb0d54b248efca89ff9b8486a&_vis_opt_preview_combination=2

It appears that the universal style rules are conflicting with my code, specifically the line that sets the box-sizing:

```
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So I've set an explicit box-sizing style on the banner with `box-sizing: content-box !important;` but it doesn't seem to override the universal style which is showing at the top in only FireFox and Safari:

[image]

Comment: **The property is clearly applying as requested otherwise it would be struck through.** Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox 43.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you don't seem to have followed the technique mentioned in the link very closely. Basically, if you **recreate** the issue in a minimal demo or Stack Snippet we can help...if not, this question is likely to be closed and attract negative attention.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this on firefox is using flexbox.

I'll be quoting from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) but with edited code to suit your question.

From the [link](http://www.goldenapplewebdesign.com/css-equally-spaced-horizontal-elements/) you provided this is the HTML structure (I'll be using it for this example):

```
<ul id="parent">
  <li>element 1</li>
  <li>element 2</li>
  <li>element 3</li>
  <li>element 4</li>
</ul>​
```

The CSS (don't forget the MDN docs I mentioned earlier):

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
}
#parent li {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%
}
```

**NOTE:** You can use any of these: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around

**NB:** Check [Can I Use - Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) to see if this solution suits you. Eg it's IE 10+